# why do i see the error 'stdin: is not a tty' when using x2go to remotely connect to several linux OS distributions?

Tags: ubuntu, xfce, x2go

I can see that several questions have been asked and answered regarding the error message `stdin: is not a TTY` with regards to SSH terminal connections between machines. However, I am using `X2goserver` and client to connect a Fedora 22 based client to a server (currently testing Ubuntu 14.04, but have used others too) and am seeing the same error after connecting.

I have looked in the SSH config file and made changes related to TTY and interactive consoles that looked like they might help the situation, but they didn't. i have also now raised a bug with the `x2go` dev team, plus asked on the Ubuntu forum but so far have not had a reply.

I think X2go is intended to take care of ensuring the correct params are passed to ensure a session is created that offers the appropriate functions for opening a GUI for the remote machine, so i am thinking this might be a bug with X2go - however, the lack of others complaining of the same issue makes me think otherwise.

For reference, I am using templates on an OpenVZ based remote server and have had `X2go` running just fine there with Fedora 20 and XFCE - but i need to upgrade now as fedora 20 is no longer being supported.

thanks

Answer (score 2):

I had this yesterday and this morning as well. I found the problem.

As part of the establishment of a session, `x2go` appears to be executing both `.bashrc` and `.bash_profile` to completion BEFORE actually presenting the session. I found that `.bash_profile` was executing `mesg y` as well as another shell script that attempted to use the value returned from `tty` as a variable (ie `` TTY=`tty` ``). Since these statements are not being executed from within a terminal they failed.  The solution is to place them inside a test as follows:

```
if `tty -s`
then
    mesg y
    TTY=`tty`
else`
    TTY='not a tty'
fi
```

This fixed it on all sites I could not connect to. I suspect a recent change in `x2go` may have brought this into focus as these sites had not changed since my last successful `x2go` connections.

Comment: You can also `if test -t 0` to avoid the call-out to `tty` itself. And ``TTY=`tty 2>&1` `` would allow `TTY` to be set outside the conditional.

Comment: Or you can set `TTY` as part of the condition and simplify the entire chunk of code to a single line: ``TTY=`tty` && mesg y` ``

Comment: actually it can be in ~/.profile as well